# Spring @CachePut response is unexpected

Tags: caching, ehcache

I am using EhCache with SpringBoot

I perform the Get operation to retrieve list and saved the response in cache.It is working fine as expected.
Now I am doing Put operation on the element  of list.Put operation is successful for that element and cache also updated.
But when  I am doing Get Operation again to retrieve list to test 
whether my update cache is working or not, I got just an element in the response who is updated instead of total list

Here is the code snippet:

```
@Override
@Cacheable(value = "practiceId", key="#practiceId", unless="#result==null")
public List<ExposedLocation> getLocations(String practiceId) {
    // getLocations list logic
}
@CachePut(value = "practiceId", key ="#practiceId")
public List<ExposedLocation> updateLocation(List<LocationDB> locationList, String practiceId) {
    //Update location logic
}
```

ehcache.xml:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="false">
<cache name="practiceId" maxEntriesLocalHeap="200" eternal="false"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" timeToLiveSeconds="600"
    timeToIdleSeconds="200">
</cache>
```

So according to my analysis of Response and some testcases I have used,
I concluded that as Response of Get and Put is different @CachePut will first remove cache and create new one
and it is putting the response of update in the new cache.

So can anyone assist me in that to retrieve full list containing updated element.
Where I am failing  to configure @CachePut??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spring caching abstraction does exactly what you ask by caching the result from either methods under the same key.
Now if indeed your methods return a different result, that's the root of the problem.

There is not built-in support for telling the cache that this list is to be merged with the currently cached one.

Comment: So you means to say that I need to add logic for backup of previous cache and then merge it into new one.correct????

Comment: Either that or make sure both methods do return results that are equivalent.